# Decrypt ciphertext in Base64

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, base64, aes

I have an Arduino Board which encrypts a string with AES and returns me the result.
Now I want to write a python script to decrypt this string.

An example of the encrypted string is the following:

```
"VNR72whV/o0gcAR/G3J3J8KT6UFrbBUCw1cO/EnNrPk="
```

The key in hex is `112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00` and the IV is `00000000000000000000000000000000`.

The decrypted string should be `hallo123hallo123`.

I created the Arduino part with a tool: [Arduino Part](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=To_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27)AES_Encrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%2700000000000000000000000000000000%27%7D,%27CBC%27,%27Raw%27,%27Hex%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)From_Hex(%27Auto%27)To_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27)&input=aGFsbG8xMjNoYWxsbzEyMw)

The Python part should work like this: [Python Part](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27,true)AES_Decrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%2700000000000000000000000000000000%27%7D,%27CBC%27,%27Raw%27,%27Hex%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)From_Hex(%27Auto%27)From_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27,true)&input=Vk5SNzJ3aFYvbzBnY0FSL0czSjNKOEtUNlVGcmJCVUN3MWNPL0VuTnJQaz0K)

I am currently using the `cryptography` library for python, but I'm open for other libs.

My python code is the following:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import base64


message = "VNR72whV/o0gcAR/G3J3J8KT6UFrbBUCw1cO/EnNrPk="
message = message.encode("ascii")
message = base64.b64decode(message)

key = bytes.fromhex('112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00')
iv = bytes.fromhex('00000000000000000000000000000000')



algorithm = algorithms.AES(key)
cipher = Cipher(algorithm, mode=modes.CBC(iv), backend=default_backend())
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
ciphertext = encryptor.update(message)

print('Key:             ', ''.join('{:02x}'.format(x) for x in key))
print('Input:           ', ''.join('{:02x}'.format(x) for x in message))
print('Ciphertext:      ', ''.join('{:02x}'.format(x) for x in ciphertext))



decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
plaintext = decryptor.update(ciphertext)
print('Plaintext:       ', ''.join('{:02x}'.format(x) for x in plaintext))

print(base64.b64decode(plaintext))
```

But it always throws an error, for example that the padding is incorrect.

And if I try to encrypt the same message `hallo123hallo123` in python, it returns `VNR72whV/o0gcAR/G3J3Jw==` which is not the same as `VNR72whV/o0gcAR/G3J3J8KT6UFrbBUCw1cO/EnNrPk=`

Comment: The error message is caused by the last line where you try to Base64 decode not Base64 encoded data.

Comment: The too short ciphertext is caused by the missing padding. Cryptography does not automatically pad, but supports various paddings, see [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/padding/?highlight=pkcs7%20padding). You need PKCS#7. Btw, the `finalize()` call is missing in the encryption (and decryption), which disguises the padding issue.

Comment: And `VNR7...rPk=` does not result from encrypting `hallo123hallo123`, but the Base64 encoding of it (where the Base64 encoding gives no advantage, so it is probably a bug).

Comment: I know that `VNR7...rPk=` comes from Base64 encoding, but I replicated the whole procedure with a tool (https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=To_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D')AES_Encrypt(%7B'option':'Hex','string':'112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00'%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':'00000000000000000000000000000000'%7D,'CBC','Raw','Hex',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)From_Hex('Auto')To_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D')&input=aGFsbG8xMjNoYWxsbzEyMw). I think the AES library for the Arduino encodes the string resulting from AES encryption to Base64

Comment: Well, then you should also post this info in the question instead of _The decrypted string should be hallo123hallo123_

Comment: Sorry if it wasnt clear, I edited the original question

Comment: The linked Cyberchef logic that the Python code is supposed to execute is only a decryption. I.e. you have to remove the encryption part `encryptor = ...` and `ciphertext = ...` from your Python code and decrypt `message` _directly_ (i.e. pass `message` in the `update()` call). Note that the `finalize()` call is missing as well as the unpadding.